# Removing preprocessor branching in C#

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I am refactoring some source code and got a task to remove preprocessor compiling. I have now searched internet for some days, but haven't found any good idea how to do that. I am also quite new to C#.

So the problem is following, I have different interfaces (classes) for every device and "ControlLogic" class needs to use only one of them at the time. Device is chosen on program run-time. 
So far "device" variable (also used globally) is used in a lot of places and considering renaming that doesn't make sense to me. Also all device interfaces (classes) are derived from base class, but interface classes does implement different methods for them.

```
public class ControlLogic
{
#if FIRST_DEVICE
        public FirstDeviceInterace device = null;
#elif SECOND_DEVICE
        public SecondDeviceInterface device = null;
#elif THIRD_DEVICE
        public ThirdDeviceInterface device = null;
#endif

// One example method
public void startDevice()
{
    if (device != null)
    {
#if (FIRST_DEVICE || SECOND_DEVICE)
         device.startDevice();
#endif

#if THIRD_DEVICE
         device.startThirdDevice();
#endif
     }
}

// More code.....
}
```

So what is the best way to remove preprocessor compiling?

Comment: What can you tell us about `FirstDeviceInterace` and the others? Is that code you could change?

Comment: You have the program which is intended to work with some specific device, with decision made at compile time. If you want to remove compile time branching, make the program smart enough to recognize the device type at runtime, so that the same program can work with any supported device. Instead of compile time constant you can keep class member variable, for example, device type.

Comment: You ought to start with an abstract base class and find commonality.  StartDevice() is already your first virtual method, surely there are more.

Comment: Yes I could change FirstDeviceInterface and other interfaces. Actually the device is recognized at the runtime and I have global variable which could be used for that. But the problem is about how do I choose specific device interface (class) depending on that?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with a similar task a few months ago: large C# code base and extensive preprocessor directives usage. Manual refactoring looked like a long boring monkey job there.
I've failed with **unifdef**, **sunifdef** and **coan** C tools because of C# syntax specifics like #region and some others. In the long run I've made my own tool [undefine](https://github.com/gaDZella/undefine). It uses regexp to parse the preprocessor directives and sympy python library to simplify logical expression. It works good for me on large 10M lines code base.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the three device types do not have a common base class or interface. You cannot just pick one of the three at runtime and type all variables with a base type.

Here are a few options:

1. Find a way to a a **common base type**.
2. If you cannot modify the classes (or it would be inappropriate for some reason) write a **wrapper**. That wrapper can have any structure you like. You could have one wrapper per device class with a common base type.
3. Use **`dynamic`**. This can be a quick fix at the cost of less tooling help (less autocompletion, less documentation at hand, less quick static error checking).

Using `#if` to solve this problem is very unusual. It is problematic because the amount of testing to even make sure the code compiles has now tripled. You also need multiple binaries.

Comment: Don't you think the OP should be given the chance to clarify before offering a complete buffet of solutions?

Comment: @HenkHolterman you might be right. On the other hand this answer will be useful for many future visitors. There is something here for many cases.

Comment: Hello! Actually the three device types (actually there are alot more) have common base class, but every type have some extra methods which other device types doesn't have.